# Django elasticsearch data synchronization

Tags: django, elasticsearch

I want to use elasticsearch to index a model in django, this model is a map of database view.
I want to know if django elasticsearch synchronized data after the storage of data in the other tables, or before that ??

Comment: You're using a library?

Comment: @mohammadJafarMashhadi I have not yet applied it, I will reply to your comment after applying it